# laravel create request not working

Tags: php, laravel

You can probably see Im very new to laravel. I have ran into an issue where it cant seem to see the new class I've made...

Firstly I ran....

```
php artisan make:request CreateSongRequest
```

which in turn generated a CreateSongRequest.php file in app/Http/Requests/

The contents...

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateSongRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            //
        ];
    }

}
```

In my controller I have the form post to the following method...

```
public function store(CreateSongRequest $request, Song $song) {


    $song->create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('songs_path');
}
```

When I submit the form, Im getting the following error...

ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 53: Class App\Http\Controllers\CreateSongRequest does not exist

Comment: My case was, there was a syntax error on the custom request class (in your case CreateSongRequest) which was preventing it from loading. So when container method was looking for it, it could not be loaded. Scrolling down the first exception revealed the second exception with the syntax error. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add this at the top of your controller:

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateSongRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It works..

```
public function store(Request $request, Song $song)
{

   $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required',
      'slug' => 'required|unique:songs,slug',
   ]);

   $song->create($request->all());
   return redirect()->route('songs_path');

}
```

Source : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation